# asp.net Styles не видит стили

Tags: asp.net-core

не могу разобратся как подлючить стили в asp.net razor 
[image: список файлов]

файл _Layout.cshtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>



<html>

    <head runat="server">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/SearchBox/index.css")" />
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

в консоле пишет

[image: в консоле пишет]

Comment: Лишние кавычки, если не ошибаюсь. `href=@Url.Content("~/Content/SearchBox/index.css")`

Comment: нет не лишние Url.Content(string[])

Comment: Повторяю: лишние кавычки перед @ и после ).